# SSRS not returning any data with Table-valued parameters

Tags: reporting-services

I'm struggling understanding why adding one or more nullable parameters before or after my table-valued parameters will return an empty recordset.

I successfully followed the example here: http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2012/06/21/using-table-valued-parameters-with-sql-server-reporting-services.aspx

Then I added an extra parameters to mimic my environment and I cannot get any more records unless I replace @accountType=NULL with @accountType=4

Here is the code in the dataset:

```
exec( ' declare @customerIdList Report.IntegerListTableType ' + @customerIdInserts +
' EXEC rpt_CustomerTransactionSummary
@startDate=''' + @startDate + ''',
@endDate=''' + @endDate + ''',
@customerIds = @customerIdList')
```

and this is the sql trace (result: empty recordset):

```
exec sp_executesql N'exec( '' declare @customerIdList Report.IntegerListTableType '' + @customerIdInserts +
'' EXEC rpt_CustomerTransactionSummary
@startDate='''''' + @startDate + '''''',
@endDate='''''' + @endDate + '''''',
@accountType='''''' + @accountType + '''''',
@customerIds = @customerIdList'')',
N'@customerIdInserts nvarchar(40),
@startDate datetime,
@endDate datetime,
@accountType int',
@customerIdInserts=N'INSERT @customerIdList VALUES (304813)',
@startDate='2013-01-01 00:00:00',
@endDate='2014-12-31 00:00:00',
@accountType=NULL
```

if I replace the NULL with a 4 and run the query in sql management studio I get the expected results:

```
exec sp_executesql N'exec( '' declare @customerIdList Report.IntegerListTableType '' + @customerIdInserts +
'' EXEC rpt_CustomerTransactionSummary
@startDate='''''' + @startDate + '''''',
@endDate='''''' + @endDate + '''''',
@accountType='''''' + @accountType + '''''',
@customerIds = @customerIdList'')',
N'@customerIdInserts nvarchar(40),
@startDate datetime,
@endDate datetime,
@accountType int',
@customerIdInserts=N'INSERT @customerIdList VALUES (304813)',
@startDate='2013-01-01 00:00:00',
@endDate='2014-12-31 00:00:00',
@accountType=4
```

Can anyone please set me to the right direction?

Thanks

rick

Answer (score 0):

I have modified my answer after you supplied the stored proc. I think accounttype will be 0 instead of null, since it is int datatype.

Try changing this:

```
  AND (accountType= @accountType OR @accountType = 0)
```

Comment: Now I have to test in my real scenario, when I can have values where zero (0) is a real value. I'll keep you posted. In the meantime THANK YOU very much

Comment: No probs, all the best.

Answer (score 0):

this is my stored proc:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.rpt_CustomerTransactionSummary
(
@startDate datetime,
@endDate datetime,
@customerIds Report.IntegerListTableType READONLY,
@accountType int
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


  SELECT t.PlayerID, t.InsertedDatetime, t.Amount 
  FROM transactions t
  INNER JOIN @customerIds AS c on t.PlayerID = c.Value
  WHERE InsertedDatetime BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate 
  AND (@accountType IS NULL OR t.AccountType=@accountType) 


END
```

Answer (score 0):

Robert your solution worked however it made us cringe to add that to the already ugly hack. We solved the issue by fixing the "Text" Query type

From

```
exec( ' declare @customerIdList Report.IntegerListTableType ' + @customerIdInserts +
' EXEC rpt_CustomerTransactionSummary
@startDate=''' + @startDate + ''',
@endDate=''' + @endDate + ''',
@accountType=''' + @accountType + ''',
@customerIds = @customerIdList')
```

to

```
DECLARE @vSQL nvarchar(max) = N'
DECLARE @customerIdList Report.IntegerListTableType; 
'+@customerIdInserts+';
EXEC rpt_CustomerTransactionSummary
@startDate=@startDate,
@endDate=@endDate,
@accountType=@accountType,
@customerIds = @customerIdList';
exec sp_executesql 
  @vSQL,
  N'@startDate datetime, @endDate datetime, @accountType int',
  @startDate,
  @endDate,
  @accountType;
```